# Increment counter for currentUser

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I would like to increment a counter for a given currentUser's key.

I'm using the [incrementKey method](http://blog.parse.com/2011/12/07/increment-operators/), however, the following code is not working*:

```
    [currentUser incrementKey:@"likes" byAmount:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    [currentUser saveInBackground];
```

- It doesn't raise an error, but it doesn't update the database either.

Comment: just to be sure, how are you assigning the currentUser variable?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that current User is a `PFUser` instance, if it is not the current logged user `[PFUser currentUser]`, probably you should have the right ACL on that user row.

Try to set the current ACL field for that user for read and write, eg:

```
// set user acl
PFACL* userACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:currentUser];
[userACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[userACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];
[currentUser setACL:userACL];
[currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    // check if any save error occurs
}];
```

Honestly, i suggest to don't use the above approach for security reason, especially on the User table. Instead you could try to make a custom function Cloud code side, using the `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` and so increment the user with something like

```
.
..
...
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
...
// retrieve the user with passed user object id from client
var userId =request.params.myUserId;
var user = new Parse.User();
user.set("objectId", userId);
user.fetch().then(function(concreteUser){

    concreteUser.increment("likes", 1);
    concreteUser.save().then(function(incrementedUser){
        response.success();
    },function(saveError){
        response.error(saveError);
    });

},function(error){
    response.error(error);
});
```

Hope it helps